# How to display one page website on desktop and multiple pages on mobile

Tags: php, html

I am currently building a portfolio website. I'd like for it to be only one page if accessed from a desktop computer (and tablet), but multiple pages via mobile browsers (phone).

I intend to do this because the content I have is too little to be on separate pages on desktop, but too much on one page for mobile (therefore increasing the reluctancy of user to go through until the end).

I believe this can be achieve with PHP? But as I'm not familiar with the language, I am not able to actually write the code.

What I'm looking for basically is this:

```
if [browser width is more than X pixels]
   [includes a file with the whole page html here],
else
   [includes a file with one page coding]
```

EDITED
My question: is it possible to do this with PHP? I am using responsive design but would like to still achieve the above (separate pages on mobile). Are there any methods other than PHP and directing the user to something like mobile.domain.com?

Comment: PHP cannot read browser information. You might want to look into JavaScript and or CSS (media queries)

Comment: use RWD http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Comment: Could probably show a different view/page based on screen size, or redirect to mobile.yourdomain.name or...

Comment: Wrong kind of question for Stack Overflow. "*... I am not able to actually write the code ...*" Unfortunately, we're not going to write it for you either. Look into hiring a web designer/developer.

Comment: @kingkero - Actually PHP can do this in a number of ways, such as `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and `get_browser`

Comment: @websky http://www.w3fools.com/ ;)

Comment: @kingkero > Yes server can access some client/browser information. In addition, there are some server-side approaches to responsiveness, and it can be of interrest some times : why serve content you know you won't be displaying at all, for example.

Answer (score 3):

To try to actually answer the question, this should get you started. There are a number of ways you can think about doing this.

#### 1. Serve different sites for Mobile vs Desktop

By detecting the user agent, it's possible to redirect users to different pages that are more appropriate for their devices. This was great about 10 years ago when you didn't have too many different devices to worry about. These day's it's not very practical.

#### 2. Responsive design

This is a slightly different way of thinking. Rather than showing different devices different information, you show them the same information and use CSS to format it to suite their screen. Notice, this is not about devices, but about screen size. This can be achieved through CSS media queries.

There are probably other ways to do it too, these are the main two I can think of. I prefer the second method, but there are *occasionally* reasons to use the first.